# `getOwners`calling the contract implementation instead of the deployed proxy on Goerli

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core

Since the Sepolia support and the new versions of the packages were deployed, I can't execute any transaction with the protocol SDK. Every call fails because `getOwners` is targeting the contract implementation instead of the deployed proxy.
I could reproduce it with the following versions on Goerli:

```
    "@safe-global/api-kit": "1.3.1",
    "@safe-global/protocol-kit": "1.3.0",
    "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types": "2.3.0",
```

and

```
    "@safe-global/api-kit": "2.0.0",
    "@safe-global/protocol-kit": "2.0.0",
    "@safe-global/safe-core-sdk-types": "3.0.1",
```

Here is the code I use to create the Safe:

```typescript
export async function getSafeFactory(
  signer: ethers.providers.JsonRpcSigner | ethers.providers.Provider
) {
  return await SafeFactory.create({
    ethAdapter: getEthersAdapterForSafe(signer),
  })
}

const safeFactory = await getSafeFactory(this.manager.signer)

const safeAccountConfig: SafeAccountConfig = {
  owners: this.params.owners,
  threshold: this.params.threshold,
}

const safeInstance: Safe = await safeFactory.deploySafe({
  safeAccountConfig,
})
const safeService = getSafeService(this.manager.signer)
const tx = await safeService.getTransaction(this.params.safeTxHash)
const executeTxResponse = await this.manager.safe.executeTransaction(tx)
const receipt =
  executeTxResponse.transactionResponse &&
  (await executeTxResponse.transactionResponse.wait())
```

We know Goerli is being deprecated, but we currently can't migrate to Sepolia yet as we have other dependencies not yet available there.
It's a blocking problem for us, please advise.
Best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Goerli is indeed [being deprecated](https://blog.ethereum.org/2023/11/30/goerli-lts-update), and won't be supported anymore. We can only advise to move to another test network. That said, our API services are still operational, including on Goerli.

Maybe you could add some context on the `getOwners` calls (not present in the snippet you shared)?

Hope it helps,
Louis